# CKEditor 5 not working on Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor, vue-composition-api

I am trying to use CKEditor with vue 3 composition api locally but the editor not shown on the page
here is may component

```
<template>
    <PageWrapper title="Post">
        <CKEditor :editor="editor"></CKEditor>
    </PageWrapper>
</template>


<script setup>
import PageWrapper from '@/components/PageWrapper.vue'
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

const editor = ClassicEditor
</script>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/vuejs-v3.html#using-the-component-locally) it's pretty straightforward, using script setup, i found it working this way

```
    
    import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
    
    const editor = ClassicEditor
    const ckeditor = CKEditor.component
```

then you can use the component in the template properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'
import {reactive}    from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        let editor = reactive(ClassicEditor);
        return {editor}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Why do you use reactive for the ClassicEditor?

Answer (score 0):

```
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
export default {
  components: {
    ckeditor: CKEditor.component
  },
  data() {
    return {
      editor: ClassicEditor,
      editorConfig: {
        
      }
    }
  }
```

then inside template

```
  <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="youModel" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
```

Works perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).